# /sys/class/bluetooth not created on startup

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I've booted up my laptop today to find that I no longer have the ability to use bluetooth. I was using all day yesterday before I shut the laptop down. When checking the status of the bluetooth service, this is what I find:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Nov 12 10:06:06 CP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Looking through syslog this is also what I'm seeing from pulseaudio/dbus:

```
Nov 12 10:06:31 CP-Laptop pulseaudio[854]: E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Further to this, I know that the service depends on the directory /sys/class/bluetooth to be present. As can be seen in the systemctl status output, that condition is returning false, and the path expected isn't present.

```
root@CP-Laptop:~# stat /sys/class/bluetooth
stat: cannot statx '/sys/class/bluetooth': No such file or directory
```

I've attempted to look for solutions, but 9/10 times the users just want it disabled, but I actively use the built in BT module for my bluetooth speakers.

I'm at a loss on what to check to try and bring my bluetooth back online. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the information on the Laptop:

```
OS - Debian Testing
HP Envy X360
  - AMD 5 2500U
  - RTL8822BE -- Bluetooth and Wifi
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as reckless as I can be, I took the laptop apart to see if there was an issue with the bluetooth module.

I wasn't able to see an issue with the hardware, but since the battery was disconnected, the CMOS was cleared. Now I have bluetooth once more.

I have no idea if the issue was with Hardware or software, but as long as it's working, I'm happy